# Guardar solamente datos que estan dentro de una latitud y longitud "X"

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy realizando web scraping a una pagina web de sismos, ya el codigo que tengo me extrae todos los datos de la tabla pero necesito que me almacene solo datos de la columna latitud y longitud que esten dentro del rango latitud = -21 y -27 y en longitud solo datos que esten dentro de -65 y -73. como puedo realizar este prodedimiento?

Hasta ahora el codigo me extrae todos los datos de la tabla y me genera un csv con ellos.

Les dejo el codigo:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd


e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

# Ejemplo de como imprimir todo
# print soup.prettify()

# Obtenemos la tabla

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

# Obtenemos todas las filas
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

output_rows = []
for row in rows:
    # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    if len(cells) > 0:
        for cell in cells:
            output_row.append(cell.text)
        output_rows.append(output_row)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)

dataset.columns = ["Fecha Local",   "Fecha UTC",    "Latitud",  "Longitud", "Profundidad [Km]", "Magnitud", "Referencia Geográfica"]


dataset.to_csv("Dataset.csv",  index=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La tarea de *scraping* ya termino por lo que la siguiente parte es el filtrado. Para ello debes hacer lo siguiente:

- Convertir la columnas de Latitud y Longitud de string a números.
- Filtrar usando los rangos.

```py
dataset = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)

dataset.columns = [
    "Fecha Local",
    "Fecha UTC",
    "Latitud",
    "Longitud",
    "Profundidad [Km]",
    "Magnitud",
    "Referencia Geográfica",
]
dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]] = dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

dataset_filter = dataset[
    (-27 <= dataset["Latitud"])
    & (dataset["Latitud"] <= -21)
    & (-73 <= dataset["Longitud"])
    & (dataset["Longitud"] <= -65)
]

dataset_filter.to_csv("Dataset.csv",  index=None)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya las lineas de codigo estan como queria, pero me falta algo al volver a ejecutar el programa se borran los datos que ya estaban. como puedo hacer para que cuando vuelva a ejecutar el programa me valla guardando los datos en las filas siguientes?